# Most efficient way to perform a deferred action in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.4

Consider a system where I have events coming in at unpredictable points in time. I want to be able to perform a "deferred" action that executes a fixed amount of time, X units, after the last event has come in. An event is considered "last" if it is the only event to have occurred in the last X units of time. What is the most efficient way to do this in Python?

One solution I have considered is using a `threading.Event`:

```
# This solution has the drawback that the deferred event may actually occur
# up to 2*X units of time after the last event.
# Also, it kinda sucks that the thread is basically polling once the first
# event comes in.


from threading import Thread
from threading import Event
import time
import sys


evt = Event()
die = False
X = 1


def thread_func_event():
    while True:
        evt.wait()
        if die:
            break

        while True:
            evt.clear()
            time.sleep(X)

            if not evt.is_set():
                # No more events came in. Good.
                break
            # Looks like more events came in. Let's try again.

            if die:
                return

        print('Deferred action performed.')
        sys.stdout.flush()


def event_occurred():
    evt.set()


t = Thread(target=thread_func_event)
t.start()

for _ in range(0, 1000000):
    event_occurred()
print('First batch of events done.')
sys.stdout.flush()

time.sleep(3)

for _ in range(0, 1000000):
    event_occurred()
print('Second batch of events done.')
sys.stdout.flush()

time.sleep(3)
die = True
evt.set()
t.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something like this before.

```
import threading
import time

class waiter(object):
    def __init__(self, action, delay = 0.5, *args, **kwargs):
        self.action_lockout_timeout = threading.Thread()
        self.action_lockout_event   = threading.Event()
        self.action                 = action
        self.delay                  = delay
        self.action_prevent()

    def action_prevent(self):
        def action_enable():
            self.action_lockout_event.wait(self.delay)
            if not self.action_lockout_event._Event__flag:
                self.action()

        if self.action_lockout_timeout.isAlive():
            self.action_lockout_event.set()
            self.action_lockout_timeout.join()
        self.action_lockout_event.clear()
        self.action_lockout_timeout = threading.Thread(target = action_enable)
        self.action_lockout_timeout.setDaemon(True)
        self.action_lockout_timeout.start()

def thanks():
    print("Person 2: Thank you ...")

polite = waiter(thanks, 3)
print("Person 1: After you")
polite.action_prevent()
time.sleep(2)
print("Person 2: No, after you")
polite.action_prevent()
time.sleep(2)
print("Person 1: No I insist")
polite.action_prevent()
time.sleep(2)
print("Person 2: But it would be rude")
polite.action_prevent()
time.sleep(2)
print("---Akward Silence---")
time.sleep(2)
```

If you want to run a function with arguments, just wrap it with a `lambda` expression.

```
def thanks(person):
    print("%s: Thank you ..." % person)

polite = waiter(lambda: thanks("Person 2"), 3)
```

**EDIT:**

Turns out that `threading.Event` is pretty slow. Here's a solution that replaces the `Event` with `time.sleep` and a `bool`. It also uses `__slots__` to speed up attribute accesses

```
import sys
import threading
import time

class waiter(object):
    __slots__ = \
    [
        "action",
        "delay",
        "undelayed",
        "delay_timeout",
    ]
    def __init__(self, action, delay = 0.5, *args, **kwargs):
        self.action        = action
        self.delay         = delay
        self.undelayed     = False
        self.delay_timeout = threading.Thread(target = self.action_enable)
        self.delay_timeout.start()

    def action_prevent(self):
        self.undelayed = False

    def action_enable(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(self.delay)
            if self.undelayed:
                self.action()
                break
            else:
                self.undelayed = True

def thanks():
    print("Person 2: Thank you ...")

polite = waiter(thanks, 1)
for _ in range(0, 1000000):
    polite.action_prevent()

print("First batch of events done.")
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem that efficient, because everytime you "interrupt", you destroy the current thread, and create a new one. Yes, that helps you meet the delay timing guarantee, but I'd rather sacrifice some of the timing guarantee for better performance. Consider the performance of this solution in the usage I exemplified in my code above, wherein there are 1000000 interruptions.

Comment: Much better, but you seem to be approaching my solution, basically :). The next optimization you can make is have a long running thread, at which point you will need some way to "signal" the thread. As you can see, I used an Event for that. One idea I got from your solution is that if the main thread can somehow determine if the worker thread is still running and looping, I can avoid calling Event.set and instead set a bool or something to indicate interruption, which will be cheaper I think. Let me think about that a bit more.

Comment: @TripShock, yes I would recommend avoiding `threading.Event` as it is slow.